# Using findElements() in the RSelenium package to select multiple dropdown items and using clickElement()

Tags: r, rselenium

I am trying to use clickElements() from the RSelenium package in order to drop down all of the downwards facing arrows in the "distrito" dropdown panel. I can do it for one of the dropdowns but I want to do it for all of them.

How can I click all of the dropdown items?

```
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4536L)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
url2 = "https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/todas-las-zonas/l"
remDr$navigate(url2)
remDr$maxWindowSize()

# accept cookies
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",'/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/footer/div/button[2]')$clickElement()
#click on Distrito
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div')$clickElement()

remDr$findElement(using = "class name", 'sui-MoleculeCheckboxField-toggleIcon')$clickElement()
```

Answer (score 1):

`findElements()` creates a list of all `webElement`s that were found. Therefore, you cannot use `clickElement()` on this list but you need to make a loop, like below:

```r
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4536L)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
url2 = "https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/todas-las-zonas/l"
remDr$navigate(url2)
remDr$maxWindowSize()

# accept cookies
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",'/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/footer/div/button[2]')$clickElement()

# click on Distrito
remDr$findElement(using = "class",'re-GeographicSearchNext')$clickElement()

# Find all checkboxes
checkboxes <- remDr$findElements(using = "class name", 're-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem')

class(checkboxes)
# [1] "list"

length(checkboxes)
# 10

# Loop for each checkbox
for (i in seq_along(checkboxes)) {
  checkboxes[[i]]$clickElement()
}
```